# How to format this data to a csv friendly format in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, formatting, analytics

Relatively simple question, I have this market data http://pastebin.com/HmiMbux5

in the form [['data',high, open, low, close, volume, etc],['data',high, open, low, close, volume, etc]]

However when saving the .txt file as a .csv and loading into excel it puts all the data in the top row.

What python code can I use to take [data],[data] and save it appropriately, I was under the impression because the [data],[data] are separated by commas it would have been compatible with excel, I was mistaken.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

cleaning up things like this is what the shell is for

```
sed 's/\]\,\[/\n/g' HmiMbux5.txt | tr -d "[]" >  HmiMbux5.csv
```

there is also a stray "min to Spreed" tacked on the end you may not want

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the response ! I forgot to mention i'm programming in python, what language is it you posted your answer in ?

Comment: the "shell"  is not always even considered a language, it is where you move around in a filesystem and call programs. If you have no idea what it is you are have pictures you click on that execute the shell commnds for you.

Comment: If you are on a unix derivative such as Mac or or Linux just bring up a terminal window and start typing, I would be glad to help. 

On MS you would have to translate to [powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell) 
which I hear has become quite capable or install a *nix work-alike such as [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/)

Comment: @tomc you can always use something like [winbash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net) which gives you the commands of the Unix terminal  in the windows cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that reads the file, and writes it to another file on disk.
only this time in correct CSV format. I tried to explain my steps in the code so I hope it is clear.

```
file = open("HmiMbux5.txt", "r")
data = file.readlines()[0] # this is still raw data.
file.close()

#now we need to purge the first and the last bracket.
index_lastbr = data.rfind("]")
intermediate_data = data[1:index_lastbr] # here I remove the encapsulating ->[<- and ->]<-
data_list_unformatted = intermediate_data.split("],[")

for index in range(len(data_list_unformatted)):
    item = data_list_unformatted[index]
    if "[" in item:
        data_list_unformatted[index] = item[1:]
    elif "]" in item:
        data_list_unformatted[index] = item[:-1]
# the data is now ["'data',high, open, low, close, volume, etc","'data',high, open, low, close, volume, etc" ]

splitted_list = [] # this becomes a list of lists where every 'column' is a separate string
for item in data_list_unformatted:
    splitted_list.append(item.split(","))

# so instead of ["'data',high, open, low, close, volume, etc","'data',high, open, low, close, volume, etc"]
# it is now [["'data'","high", "open", "low", "close", "volume", "etc"],["'data'","high", "open", "low", "close", "volume", "etc"]]

newfile = open("corrected_data.csv", "w") # here we start writing it to a file

newfile.write('"data";high;open;low;close;volume;etc;\n')

for listitem in splitted_list:
    for item in listitem:
        newfile.write(item + ";")
    newfile.write("\n")

newfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. In all honesty i was expecting the code to be shorter, not that this is a problem, it's just interesting. Thanks again

Comment: your code just puts each line in one cell, it should be separated by the commas

Comment: hmmm.... I tried it and when I opened the file with [excel](http://imgur.com/bq0bhvj) this is what I got... (this is the new file generated)